# RegEx: text that contains any match letter in sequence

Tags: regex

is it possible to have a regex to search a person's name. say if I enter 'fb' it would match the word 'foobar'?

Comment: *Why* would it match `foobar`? Because of FooBar?

Comment: what are your matching conditions? what happens if someone else enters `noname`?

Comment: So basically if a bunch of letters are in a string in the correct order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can match any letter in sequence by using `.*` **before** all the words.

So,in your case it would be `.*f.*b`

---

`.*` could cause a lot of backtracking in case you have more than two words and if there are multiple such words.You can instead use `.*?` which would match lazily and thus avoid backtracking

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to answer that.

- `[fb]` and `(f|b)` will match any character that is either a `f` or a `b`;
- `f+b+` will match anything that starts with a `f` and has a `b` before a line break;
- most importantly, do your own homework. Go read some good books or sites about regex.

Answer (score 0):

You might use: `f\w+b\w+`. Remember to use "Ignore case" option. This might be also achieved by adding `(?i)` at the beginning of the regexp.

[Example with Regexp Debugger](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=f%5Cw%2bb%5Cw%2b&str=FooBar%20foobaz%20foofoo&flags=i)